# Terraform - Configuration tuple depending on expression and instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to have a dynamic configuration for an Application Load Balancer. Depending on what the var.execution_type contains (screening or monitoring) I would like to have the proper configuration for it in target groups of load balancer. The issue I'm having is that if the execution_type is monitoring it also has to provide the instance_id of the machine where to forward the request. **This instance on the other hand is only created if execution_type is 'screening'(count = var.execution_type == "monitoring" ? 0 : 1).** This is how my code looks like:

```
target_groups = var.execution_type == "monitoring" ? [
#static configuration block
] : [
targets = {
   screening_machine = {
      target_id = var.execution_type == "monitoring" ? null : module.screening_machine.id
      port = 80
      }
   }
]
```

The errors I'm facing are these:

```
module.screening_machine is a list of object, known only after apply
var.execution_type is a string, known only after apply

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are tuple and tuple,
│ respectively.
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
The whole resource block:

```
module "alb" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/alb/aws"
  version = "6.6.1"


  name = "${local.resource_prefix}-lb-frontend"

  load_balancer_type = "application"

  vpc_id          = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnets         = module.vpc.public_subnets
  security_groups = ["${module.vpc.default_security_group_id}", "${aws_security_group.allow_http.id}"]

  target_groups = var.execution_type == "monitoring" ? [
    {
      name             = "frontend-target-group"
      backend_protocol = "HTTP"
      backend_port     = 80
      target_type      = "ip"
      health_check = {
        enabled             = true
        interval            = 30
        path                = "/"
        port                = "traffic-port"
        healthy_threshold   = 5
        unhealthy_threshold = 2
        timeout             = 2
        protocol            = "HTTP"
        matcher             = "200"
      }
    }

  ] : [
    {
      name             = "frontend-target-group"
      backend_protocol = "HTTP"
      backend_port     = 80
      target_type      = "ip"
      health_check = {
        enabled             = true
        interval            = 30
        path                = "/"
        port                = "traffic-port"
        healthy_threshold   = 5
        unhealthy_threshold = 2
        timeout             = 2
        protocol            = "HTTP"
        matcher             = "200"
      }
    },{
      name             = "screening_machine"
      backend_protocol = "HTTP"
      backend_port     = 80
      target_type      = "instance"
      health_check = {
        enabled             = true
        interval            = 30
        path                = "/ec"
        port                = "traffic-port"
        healthy_threshold   = 5
        unhealthy_threshold = 2
        timeout             = 2
        protocol            = "HTTP"
        matcher             = "200"
      }
      targets = {
        screening_machine = {
          target_id = module.screening_machine.instance_id != null ? module.screening_machine.instance_id : null
          port = 80
        }
      }
    }

  ]


  http_tcp_listeners = [
    {
      port        = 80
      protocol    = "HTTP"
      action_type = "redirect"
      redirect = {
        port        = "443"
        protocol    = "HTTPS"
        status_code = "HTTP_301"
      }
    }
  ]
  https_listeners = [
    {
      port               = 443
      protocol           = "HTTPS"
      certificate_arn    = data.aws_acm_certificate.subdomain_certificate.arn
      target_group_index = 0
    }

  ]
  
  https_listener_rules = var.execution_type == "monitoring" ? [
    {
      https_listener_index = 0
      priority             = 5000

      actions = [
        {
          type = "authenticate-cognito"

          user_pool_arn       = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_arn
          user_pool_client_id = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_client_id
          user_pool_domain    = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_domain
        },
        {
          type               = "forward"
          target_group_index = 0
        }
      ]

      conditions = [{
        path_patterns = ["/csv-table", "/json-display/*", "/processed-files", "/results/*"]
      }]
    }
  ]:[
    {
      https_listener_index = 0
      priority             = 5000

      actions = [
        {
          type = "authenticate-cognito"

          user_pool_arn       = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_arn
          user_pool_client_id = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_client_id
          user_pool_domain    = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_domain
        },
        {
          type               = "forward"
          target_group_index = 0
        }
      ]

      conditions = [{
        path_patterns = ["/csv-table", "/json-display/*", "/processed-files", "/results/*"]
      }]
    },
    {
      https_listener_index = 0
      priority             = 4000

      actions = [
        {
          type = "authenticate-cognito"

          user_pool_arn       = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_arn
          user_pool_client_id = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_client_id
          user_pool_domain    = module.cognito.cognito_user_pool_domain
        },
        {
          type               = "forward"
          target_group_index = 1
        }
      ]
      conditions = [{
        path_patterns = ["/ec", "/ec/*"]
      }]
    }
  ]
  

  tags = local.tags
}
```

Comment: Can you add the entire resource block and not only one part of it?

Comment: I didn't initially because it was 170 lines long, I edited the post to include that as well..

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest writing your own module with conditionals on the resource level.

for example:

```
variable "execution_type" {}

resource "aws_lb" "lb" {}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "monitoring" {
  count = var.execution_type == "monitoring" ? 0 : 1
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "screening_1" {
  count = var.execution_type == "screening" ? 0 : 1
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "screening_2" {
  count = var.execution_type == "screening" ? 0 : 1
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "attach_2" {
  count            = var.execution_type == "screening" ? 0 : 1
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.screening_2[0].arn
  target_id        = module.screening_machine.instance_id
  port             = 80
}
```

Aditionally, you can try with `try()` function on output of the `instance_id` from `screening_machine` module.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  count = <condition>? 0 : 1
}
output "instance_id" {
  value = try(aws_instance.ec2[0].id, "")
}
```

If it will still throw `module.screening_machine is a list of object, known only after apply` then you need to do the same as in this post: [Terraform loop over subnet ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415656/terraform-loop-over-subnet-ids)