# Terraform loop over subnet ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, count, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

I have a VPC module which creates private subnets

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each          = { for index, az_name in local.az_names : index => az_name }
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.network.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.network.cidr_block, 8, each.key + 11)
  availability_zone = local.az_names[each.key]
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.env}-private-${local.az_names[each.key]}"
    Description = local.az_names[each.key]
    Type = "private"
  }
}
```

And an output

```
output "private_subnet" {
  value = aws_subnet.private
}
```

Now I am trying to create an EFS module which will create a mount target for each private subnet

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {
  count = length(var.private_subnet)
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
  subnet_id = var.private_subnet[count.index].id
  security_groups = var.security_groups
}
```

main.tf

```
module "efs" {
  source              = "./modules/efs"
  env                 = var.env
  vpc_id           = module.vpc.vpc_id
  security_groups = [module.security.efs_sg_ids]
  private_subnet = module.vpc.private_subnet
}
```

But I am getting these errors

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on modules/efs/main.tf line 14, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt":
│   14:   subnet_id = var.private_subnet[count.index].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number, known only after apply
│     │ var.private_subnet is a string, known only after apply
│ 
│ This value does not have any indices.
```

Comment: Could you show `local.az_names`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `count` and `for_each` meta-arguments which is not a good idea. To fix that, you could do the following:

1. Leave the `count` meta-argument in the EFS resource but change the output of the VPC module
2. Use `for_each` with the EFS module as well

Even though I would suggest the second approach, I will provide both options. In the output in the VPC module, you can switch to:

```
output "private_subnet" {
  value = values(aws_subnet.private)[*].id
}
```

The `values` built-in function [1] will return a list of subnet IDs which you can then use as the intended input for the EFS module. In this case, you would have to change the module input variable type from `string` to `list(string)`:

```
variable "private_subnet" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of subnet IDs."
}
```

On the other hand, you could try switching the EFS resource to use `for_each` instead of `count` and passing it the output value of the VPC module the way it currently is:

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {
  for_each        = var.private_subnet
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
  subnet_id       = each.value.id
  security_groups = var.security_groups
}
```

In this case, you would have to change the module input variable type from `string` to `map(any)`:

```
variable "private_subnet" {
  type        = map(any)
  description = "Map of all the values returned by the subnet resource."
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values

Comment: I tried both ways but am still getting errors. The first way give me the same error and the 2nd │   on main.tf line 62, in module "efs":
│   62:   private_subnet = module.vpc.private_subnet
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "private_subnet" defined at
│ modules/efs/variables.tf:19,1-26: string required.

Comment: What is the variable definition for `private_subnet`?

Comment: variable "private_subnet" {
  type = string
}

Comment: Ah, ok, for the first solution it would have to be `type = list(string)`.

Comment: You would also have to adjust it for the second value you are passing to the module, let me just think which type it should be and I'll update the answer accorgingly.

Comment: It is working now with the 2nd solution and map as the variable type. thanks for your help

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated!